# Cropping a specified CGRect from a video in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avvideocomposition

I want to crop a specified region of CGRect from my video file.
I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.one-dreamer.com/cropping-video-square-like-vine-instagram-xcode/) .

I'm using `renderSize` property of `AVMutableVideoComposition` to get to a specified size. Here is my code that I use to crop a video to a specified size.

```
- (void) cropVideoAtPath:(NSString *) path
{
  //load our movie Asset
  AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

  //create an avassetrack with our asset
  AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

  //create a video composition and preset some settings
  AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
  videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
  //here we are setting its render size to its height x height (Square)

  float deltaHeight = 100;

  videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height-deltaHeight);

 //create a video instruction
  AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = 
 [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
  instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60, 30));

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* transformer [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:clipVideoTrack];

 //    CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 1000);
 //    CGAffineTransform finalTransform = t1;
 //    [transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];

instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:transformer];
videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

//Create an Export Path to store the cropped video
NSString * documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *exportPathLoc = [documentsPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/CroppedVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPathLoc];

//Remove any prevouis videos at that path
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]  removeItemAtURL:exportUrl error:nil];

//Export
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality] ;
exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition;
exporter.outputURL = exportUrl;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
 {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         NSLog(@"Saved");
         UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([[exporter outputURL] path],nil,nil,nil);

     });
 }];
 }
```

My original video look like this one. [image]

My video after applying `renderSize` to `AVMutableVideoComposition` look like this one. [image]

As we can see bottom portion are successfully clipped away from original video.

Lets say I have a video with size `(1000,1000)` and I want only the center portion `(500,500)` region of that video. So my `CGrect` would be `(0,250,500,500)`. 
In my case I want only the region where image is present and so I want to crop out top bar and bottom bar.

So I applied `CGAffineTransform` to the `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` like this

```
CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, deltaHeight);
CGAffineTransform finalTransform = t1;
[transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

which resulted like this below image.

[image]

So how can I apply this `(x,y)` value in cropping the video and what am I doing wrong in here . I would appreciate any help.

Comment: any updates about it?

Comment: iam also facing same issues @Jaffer Sheriff you got any solution for this??